# Remove file type icons from file navigation tabs in IntelliJ/PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have been struggling to remove the icons from the tabs menu of my main navigation in PhpStorm. I also tried to find a way on IntelliJ forum but with no luck can you please suggest how to remove these icons from my tabs.

[image: PhpStorm tab img]

Comment: I know how to remove the icon by editing the icons.jar, but it won't save you the space. The Icon will be invisible. Would you like me to write an answer?

Comment: this padding is just hurting me .. it takes a lot of space from top to bottom .. it will be perfect if this spacing issue resolved with icon disappearing . whether it?

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no option for that but this is going to be implemented in nearest future: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161894